# Finding the probability density function of $Y=\exp(X^2)$, where $X$ is standard normal and expectation of $Y^2$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, expected-value

The question is finding the expectation of $Y^2$ when $Y=\exp(X^2)$ and $X\sim N(0,1 )$.

I tried to solve it by using the cumulative distribution and derivation of it.

\begin{align}
F_Y(y)=P(Y<y)=P(e^{X^2}<y)&=P(X^2<\ln y)
\\&=2P(0<X<\sqrt{\ln y})
\\&=2\int_0^\sqrt{\ln y}f(x)\,dx
\end{align}

$$f_Y(y)=\frac{f(\sqrt{\ln y})}{y\sqrt{\ln y}}=\frac{y^{-3/2}}{\sqrt{\ln y}\sqrt{2\pi}}$$

But the formula looks too messy and I couldn't get the expectation of $Y^2$ by myself.

Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

No need to find the distribution of $Y$.

$EY=\frac  1{\sqrt {2\pi}} \int e^{x^{2}} e^{-x^{2}/2}dx=\infty$ which implies that $EY^{2}$ is also $\infty$.